# Restricting Uniques from Showing

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates

I currently have this SQL query and this output.

```
SELECT b.HotelNo,g.guestName,b.dateFrom,b.dateToFrom Booking b, Guest g
FROM Booking b, Guest g
WHERE b.guestNo = g.guestNo
GROUP BY b.hotelNo,b.dateFrom,b.dateTo,g.guestName;
```

I am getting this output:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVOqn.png)

How do I remove all the rows that are not duplicates of first two columns?

Output would be (In words Get all the hotel numbers guest names and dates of stay of all guest only if they have stayed in the same hotel more than once):

```
1234 John Doe 2017-02-01 00:00:00.000 2017-02-28 00:00:00.000
1234 John Doe 2017-03-16 00:00:00.000 2017-03-21 00:00:00.000
```

**EDIT:**
I got what I wanted but I when I add `b.dateFrom,b.dateTo` into my select statement. I get an error saying: `Column 'Booking.dateFrom' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

This is the SQL query that gets this error:

```
SELECT b.hotelNo,g.guestName,b.dateFrom,b.dateTo 
FROM Booking b, Guest g 
WHERE b.guestNo = g.guestNo
GROUP BY b.hotelNo,g.guestName 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

If I add those two column names in (which I need) I get the error above. How do I add them in without getting an error?

Comment: Can you clarify? Your statement, "How do I remove all the rows that are not duplicates..." indicated de-duplication. Your statement "get ... only if they have stayed in the same hotel more than once." indicates keeping only duplicates.

Comment: @M.K.Hunter So I get that out put in the picture above, As you can see `John Doe` stayed in the same Hotel `Hotel Number: 1234` But none of the other guest stayed at the same hotel more than once. I want to keep the 1st and 3rd row in the picture and filter out the rest of them.

Comment: First of all, as a general rule, you should use explicit join syntax, e.g. `FROM Booking AS b JOIN Guest AS g ON b.guestNo = g.guestNo`. As for your problem, one way would be to either join or use `exists` to select only those who have a count greater than two. e.g. `WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM booking WHERE hotelno = b.hotelno AND guestno = b.guestno GROUP BY hotelno, guestno HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)`. Join syntax might look like this: `JOIN (SELECT hotelno, guestno FROM booking GROUP BY hotelno, guestno HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) AS J ON J.hotelno = B.hotelno AND J.guestno = B.guestno`.

Comment: @ZLK I tried yours and it didn't completely work, but I did add the `HAVING COUNT(*)`. See the edited portion below the `Edit` section.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear but I'll add what I was actually suggesting as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want only those who have stayed in a hotel more than once, use either a JOIN or an EXISTS clause to check whether the count is greater than two.

Using `EXISTS`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.hotelNo,g.guestName,b.dateFrom,b.dateTo 
FROM Booking AS b
JOIN Guest AS g 
    ON b.guestNo = g.guestNo
WHERE EXISTS 
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM Booking
    WHERE hotelNo = b.hotelNo
    AND guestNo = b.guestNo
    GROUP BY hotelNo, guestNo
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
);
```

Using a `JOIN` (but same principle):

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.hotelNo,g.guestName,b.dateFrom,b.dateTo 
FROM Booking AS b
JOIN Guest AS g 
    ON b.guestNo = g.guestNo
JOIN
(
    SELECT hotelNo, guestNo
    FROM Booking
    GROUP BY hotelNo, guestNo
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) AS j
    ON j.hotelNo = b.hotelNo
    AND j.guestNo = b.guestNo;
```

**NOTE:** I'm not sure that you need `DISTINCT` or a `GROUP BY` on your columns unless you actually have duplicates in your tables (and if you do, you probably should get rid of those duplicates).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind picking only one of the "dateFrom"s (first or last depending on the order clause) then you can assign a row number to each row, partitioning by the first two columns.
Then only pick the first rows of each group (RN=1) which has the same first two column

```
WITH CTE AS
( SELECT ROW_NUMBER()   
          OVER ( PARTITION BY b.HotelNo,g.guestName 
            ORDER BY b.dateFrom) AS RN,
         b.HotelNo,g.guestName,b.dateFrom,b.dateTo
  FROM Booking b, Guest g
  WHERE b.guestNo = g.guestNo
  GROUP BY b.hotelNo,b.dateFrom,b.dateTo,g.guestName;
)
SELECT HotelNo,guestName,dateFrom,dateToFrom 
WHERE RN=1
```

You can read more [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql)